# Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’

Tags: haskell

Full code http://codepad.org/of3mTarF

I'm trying to use [monad-mock](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-mock) to test my code, but I run into a problem which I have no idea how to solve.

The monad I'm trying to mock:

```
class Monad m => MonadAccess m where
  getItem :: FromJSON a => ItemId -> m a
  getNextPage :: (FromJSON a, Show a, Eq a) => Pager a -> m (Maybe (Pager a))
```

I also have a function which is defined in terms of that monad:

```
getAllPages
  :: (MonadAccess m, FromJSON a, Show a, Eq a)
  => String
  -> m [a]
getAllPages s = do
    firstPage <- getItem s
    go (pagerItems firstPage) (pagerNext firstPage)
  where
    go acc mp =
      case mp of
        Nothing -> return acc
        Just p  -> getNextPage p >>= go (acc ++ pagerItems p)
```

I define the mock using TemplateHaskell:

```
makeAction "AccessAction" [ts| MonadAccess |]
```

But even if I define all the necessary bits manually the errors I'm getting are the same:

```
mock.hs:65:1: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          eqAction :: forall a b.
                      AccessAction a
                      -> AccessAction b -> Maybe (a Data.Type.Equality.:~: b)
        at mock.hs:65:1
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          eqAction :: forall a b.
                      AccessAction a
                      -> AccessAction b -> Maybe (a Data.Type.Equality.:~: b)
        at mock.hs:65:1
      Expected type: Maybe (a Data.Type.Equality.:~: b)
        Actual type: Maybe (a Data.Type.Equality.:~: a)
    • In the expression: Just Data.Type.Equality.Refl
      In the expression:
        if (&&) ((==) x_amxO y_amxP) True then
            Just Data.Type.Equality.Refl
        else
            Nothing
      In an equation for ‘eqAction’:
          eqAction (GetItem x_amxO) (GetItem y_amxP)
            = if (&&) ((==) x_amxO y_amxP) True then
                  Just Data.Type.Equality.Refl
              else
                  Nothing
    • Relevant bindings include
        eqAction :: AccessAction a
                    -> AccessAction b -> Maybe (a Data.Type.Equality.:~: b)
          (bound at mock.hs:65:1)

mock.hs:65:1: error:
    • Could not deduce: a2 ~ a1
      from the context: (a ~ Maybe (Pager a1),
                         FromJSON a1,
                         Show a1,
                         Eq a1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   GetNextPage :: forall a_Xe30.
                                  (FromJSON a_Xe30, Show a_Xe30, Eq a_Xe30) =>
                                  Pager a_Xe30 -> AccessAction (Maybe (Pager a_Xe30)),
                 in an equation for ‘eqAction’
        at mock.hs:65:1-45
      or from: (b ~ Maybe (Pager a2), FromJSON a2, Show a2, Eq a2)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   GetNextPage :: forall a_Xe30.
                                  (FromJSON a_Xe30, Show a_Xe30, Eq a_Xe30) =>
                                  Pager a_Xe30 -> AccessAction (Maybe (Pager a_Xe30)),
                 in an equation for ‘eqAction’
        at mock.hs:65:1-45
      ‘a2’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          GetNextPage :: forall a_Xe30.
                         (FromJSON a_Xe30, Show a_Xe30, Eq a_Xe30) =>
                         Pager a_Xe30 -> AccessAction (Maybe (Pager a_Xe30)),
        in an equation for ‘eqAction’
        at mock.hs:65:1
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          GetNextPage :: forall a_Xe30.
                         (FromJSON a_Xe30, Show a_Xe30, Eq a_Xe30) =>
                         Pager a_Xe30 -> AccessAction (Maybe (Pager a_Xe30)),
        in an equation for ‘eqAction’
        at mock.hs:65:1
      Expected type: Pager a1
        Actual type: Pager a2
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘y_amxR’
      In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(==) x_amxQ y_amxR’
      In the expression: (&&) ((==) x_amxQ y_amxR) True
    • Relevant bindings include
        y_amxR :: Pager a2 (bound at mock.hs:65:1)
        x_amxQ :: Pager a1 (bound at mock.hs:65:1)
```

I tried removing `Maybe` from the definition of the `getNextPage` but it didn't change anything. I also looked into [Data.Type.Equality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html) but I couldn't figure out what may be wrong.

Any pointers to get this piece of code to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's try this again.  If we use the `-ddump-splices` switch, and massage the output a little, we see what `makeAction` generated:

```
data AccessAction r
  where
    GetItem :: FromJSON a => ItemId -> AccessAction a
    GetNextPage :: (FromJSON a, Show a, Eq a) =>
                   Pager a -> AccessAction (Maybe (Pager a))
deriving instance Eq (AccessAction r)
deriving instance Show (AccessAction r)

instance Action AccessAction where
  eqAction (GetItem x) (GetItem y)
    = if x == y then
          Just Refl
      else
          Nothing
  eqAction (GetNextPage x) (GetNextPage y)
    = if x == y True then
          Just Refl
      else
          Nothing
  eqAction _ _ = Nothing

instance Monad m =>
         MonadAccess (MockT AccessAction m) where
  getItem x = mockAction "getItem" (GetItem x)
  getNextPage x = mockAction "getNextPage" (GetNextPage x)
```

The error occurs when creating the `eqAction` function for the `AccessAction` instance of `Action`.  The function for this instance has type:

```
eqAction :: AccessAction a -> AccessAction b -> Maybe (a :~: b)
```

Which means it will be passed two `AccessAction`s with potentially different result types, and must return `Nothing` if the two actions are different, or `Just Refl` if the two actions are the same (meaning they have the same data constructor, equal arguments, and matching return types).

The `AccessAction` constructors have type:

```
GetItem :: FromJSON a => ItemId -> AccessAction a
GetNextPage :: (FromJSON a, Show a, Eq a) => Pager a -> AccessAction (Maybe (Pager a))
```

The `eqAction` function pattern matches on the constructors, checks that the arguments are equal, and returns `Just Refl` if they are.  However, `Refl` inhabits `a :~: b` iff `a ~ b`, but there's no constraint that guarantees that `a ~ b`, which results in the error.  For example, one `GetItem` could be an `AccessAction Int`, and the other an `AccessAction Bool`, since both `Int` and `Bool` have `FromJSON` instances.

You would need to prove that the two `FromJSON` instances are the same type.  The only way I can see to do this would be if `AccessAction` had a `TestEquality` instance, which would require the `a` to also have a `TestEquality` instance.

Rather, we can make `a` a parameter to the `MonadAccess` typeclass with a functional dependency (just like the state parameter in `MonadState`), and move the `FromJSON, Eq, and Show` constraints into the typeclass:

```
class (FromJSON a, Show a, Eq a, Monad m) => MonadAccess a m | m -> a where
  getItem :: ItemId -> m (Pager a)
  getNextPage :: Pager a -> m (Maybe (Pager a))
```

This requires that we add the `FunctionalDependencies` language extension.

Note that I also changed the return type of `getItem` from `m a` to `m (Pager a)`, which is how it is used in practice (the compile gets upset if the type is too general).

The type of `getAllPages` now changes to:

```
getAllPages
  :: MonadAccess a m
  => String
  -> m [a]
```

And we can finally use `makeAction` to generate a mock for `MonadAccess Item` (which is the type of `a` we intend to use in the mock).

```
makeAction "AccessAction" [ts| MonadAccess Item |]
```

The generated code creates a context with `FromJSON Item`, which is not allowed unless you enable the `FlexibleContexts` language extension.

Now we have a guarantee that, within `MonadAccess Item`, all `a` type variables refer to the same type `Item`.